# Query Optimization

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-optimization

I have a query in Microsoft Access, that needs c.a 6 seconds to return 1000 records.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tb_bauteile.*
FROM   tb_bauteile
       LEFT JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste
         ON tb_bauteile.CDT = FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT
WHERE  (( ( FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Steuergerät ) = 'MEDC17' ))
ORDER  BY FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad;
```

I put index on the neccessary fields.
**tb_bauteile** has c.a 3000 records and **FehlerCodes_akt_Liste** has c.a 20000 records. If I delete **Where** and **order** Clause the query returns the records very fast.
How can I optimize my query?

Comment: Try add index on the column FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad

Comment: I have an index on Fehlerpfad

Comment: Where are the records coming from? A local Access back-end? An Access back-end on the network? Elsewhere? Which is the smaller table?

Comment: Records come from a Backend , but nicht local and I use LAN

Comment: Can you test with a copy on your local machine? I strongly suspect that this is a network problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ...

```
tb_bauteile LEFT JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste
```

But then this `WHERE` clause ...

```
FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Steuergerät = 'MEDC17'
```

That constraint makes the `LEFT JOIN` moot ... your result set will include only rows where you have matches between `tb_bauteile.CDT` and `FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT`.  You may as well switch to an `INNER JOIN` which should be faster.

Here are some other issues to examine.

1. Do you notice any performance impact if you remove `DISTINCTROW`?
2. So you have indexes on `CDT`, `Steuergerät`, and `Fehlerpfad`.  Have you also performed a compact operation (which updates the statistics)?
3. Examine the query plan which is created for your query.  It can be challenging to interpret, but perhaps it will turn up something useful.  [Use Microsoft Jet's ShowPlan to write more efficient queries](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/use-microsoft-jets-showplan-to-write-more-efficient-queries/5064388)

Comment: Thankyou Hansup for your answer could you please explain the Point number 2 a little bit in detail?

Comment: Read the section under the heading "Periodically compact your Microsoft Jet database" at this page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303528